# b-field value is getting updated only @select and not @input?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I am using the Buefy UI components in my VueJS project. I have a drop-down in a page:

```
<b-field label="Business Unit">
      <b-autocomplete
        :data="dataBusinessUnit"
        placeholder="select a business unit..."
        field="businessUnit"
        :loading="isFetching"
        :value="this.objectData.businessUnit"
        @typing="getAsyncDataBusinessUnit"
        @select="(option) => {updateValue(option.id,'businessUnit')}"
      >
        <template slot-scope="props">
          <div class="container">
            <p>
              <b>ID:</b>
              {{props.option.id}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Description:</b>
              {{props.option.description}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </template>
        <template slot="empty">No results found</template>                
      </b-autocomplete>
    </b-field>
```

As you can see from the above code, the `updateValue` function is responsible for updating the value, but it will currently be called only when the user selects something from the drop-down suggestions. I want the value to be updated even when the user starts to type something. Example: `@input="(newValue)=>{updateValue(newValue,'businessUnit')}"`. However, there is already a debounce function called `getAsyncDataBusinessUnit` that I am calling to fetch the filtered autocomplete results based on what the user has typed during the `@typing` event.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Buefy Autocomplete API documentation found [here](https://buefy.org/documentation/autocomplete/#api-view), you could probably use `v-model` instead of using `value` directly.

Alternatively you could actually implement the `@input` like you wrote yourself, the `@typing` event shouldn't interfere with it.

Or you could just handle the value updating in `@typing`:

```js
@typing="onTyping"

// then later in JS...
methods: {
  onTyping(value) {
    this.updateValue(value, 'businessUnit')
    this.getAsyncDataBusinessUnit(value)
  },
}
```